# Sublime text3 update has broken my flatland theme

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am on Sublime Text 3. Has anyone experienced same problem as I have since recent update(Ver. 3065)?

I use Flatland theme.

And know how to fix it??

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you've experienced problem with some product, you should probably report a bug to that product's developers team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry. I dont know what happened to my USER setting.

But something(package?) inserted `ignored_theme` line into my USER setting.

Don't know who(maybe the update) did this, i just deleted `igonored_theme` from my USER setting, and now it works all fine.

Comment: This is because ST disables all packages while updating, then it should've enabled it again but for some reason did not. Please mark your own answer as accepted

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky Thanks for the notice. Prob. my internet connection went wrong at that time.